# Load Bearing Weight Capacity of a 3/4“ x 3/4” Wood Molding?

Tags: load-bearing, door-frame

I'd like to custom install Ikea PAX sliding doors into my existing closets, recessing them into the closet opening. My idea is to create a custom "frame" simulating the Ikea closet frame onto which to install the Ikea mounting hardware. The Ikea hardware is designed to slide onto a 3/4" thick frame.

My question is: would a 3/4" x 3/4" wood molding screwed onto a 1.5" x 6" or a 2" x 6" wood plank be able to support the 130 lb Ikea doors? The top rail would be screwed onto the molding and the weight of the sliding doors would rest entirely upon this molding.

See the photo below to illustrate the design. In this picture the sliding doors would be mounted to the molding and the doors would face left (the inside of the closet would be to the right).

I can screw the molding to the larger wood piece every foot and also use wood glue between them. I have no experience in wood working and such a small molding seems like it might not hold up. Thanks!

[image: design of custom frame for sliding doors]

Comment: you keep saying moulding.  Are you talking abut trim or a 3/4" spacer or jam extender?  I'm confused.

Comment: If pre drilled the 3/4 x3/4 might hold and not split but the supports for the door need to go into the 2x6 just use the 3/4 as a spacer and it should hold the weight. If screwing only into the 3/4 it would need more of a piano hinge with screws every 2-3".

Comment: Link to the door hardware? I'm failing to see why IKEA deemed it necessary to reinvent how you hang a sliding door, but I'm not surprised ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what kind of wood you're planning to use, which does make a big difference in this case but assuming you're going to use pine/poplar or some similar readily available wood my answer would be no, the 3/4 "cleat" is not going to hold up. My first thought is that if your dimensions are limited in the way your drawing implies, what about a piece of angle iron, or something similar?